# Network request using redux toolkit and axios behaving weiredly

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit

This is the action that i send and check the last line `return rejectWithValue(error.message);`

```
  "AdminAuthorMentorAuth/login",
  async ({ email, password }: LoginI, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const user = await api.post(
        "auth/login",
        {
          email,
          password,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      );
      if (user.data.check) {
        return { loggedState: true, email: user.data.user.email };
      } else {
        setAxiosToken(user.data.token);
        saveToken(user.data.getToken);
        console.log(user);
        return user.data.user;
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
      if (error.response.data) {
        return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.fallbackMessage);
      } else {
        console.log("Error", error);
        return rejectWithValue(error.message);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

```
  try {
    setCurrentStatus(status.loading);
    const res = await dispatch(
      login({ email, password: password.value })
    ).unwrap();
    if (res.loggedState) {
      setCurrentStatus(status.askConfirmation);
      setRequestEmail(res.email);
    }
    if (!res.loggedState) navigate("/");
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log("error", error);
    setCurrentStatus(status.failed);
    setRequestError(error);
  }
}
```

I am dispatching this action from one component.
using axios for netwwork request

So, my question is when i change the  `return rejectWithValue(error.message);`
in the action to `return error`, this doesnot end in the catch block of my handlebuttonclick function in my component rather it ends inside the try block. I want to know why its happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would `createAsyncThunk` know that something you `return` should be handled as an error without you being explicit about it?

The distinction is:

- you `throw` it: an error
- you `return rejectWithValue(...)`: an error
- you `return fulfillWithValue(...)`: normal return
- you `return ...`: normal return

Comment: As it is a catch block so, its handling error? Am i wrong?

Comment: If you do a normal `return` from a `catch` block, the assumption would be that you have handled the error and everything is back to how it should be without the error.